# Is asking on philosophy on topic?

Tags: discussion

Science used to be considered as second philosophy. PhD, the highest title for a scientist, is a Doctor of Philosophy. However, some philosophers opine that [philosophy is not science](http://chronicle.com/blogs/brainstorm/is-philosophy-a-science/45795). So, is asking on philosophy on topic here?

Comment: Are you talking about philosophy of science, or history of philosophy? And if the answer is "no", would questions about "natural philosophers" like Galileo and Newton suddenly become off-topic?

Comment: I mean the philosophy itself, but the philosophy of science is also a good question

Comment: Philosophy of science and math is certainly ok if there is enough historical context. But philosophy as a whole would be too broad a field and there are so many questions that can be asked on it. I think it should only be philosophy of math and science.

Comment: @ManjilP.Saikia: I think [Philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) is a better site to ask

Comment: @Ooker But then we could say the same about HSM and say maybe we can use math.SE for the history of math questions?

Comment: @ManjilP.Saikia: Then again we can use Physics.SE to ask the history of physics, Biology.SE to ask the history of biology... :-s

Comment: Yes thats what I mean, so I think philosophy of science and math in a historical context should be okay. But I am hard pressed to give a definitive example.

Comment: Maybe this site to other specific sites is like ELL to ELU?

Answer (score 5):

**Philosophy** and **History of Philosophy** I would consider *off topic* and is better for [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

This is because that is *still* in scope at [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/). On the other hand

**History of Philosophy of Science and Mathematics** should be considered on-topic. This includes meta-mathematics, meta-physics, scientific method etc.

Comment: The reason these kinds of questions are in scope of Philosophy.SE doesn't necessary make them off-topic here.

Comment: @Ooker However those who are experts in Philosophy are more likely to be found in Philosophy.SE rather than here.

Comment: So if someone ask it here, the question is still on-topic. Unless "no philosophy" is hard written on the "What topics should I ask?", I can't find any reason to vote it off-topic.

Comment: @Ooker If it is about history of philosophy and/or philosophy itself, this site is not the place for it. If the philosophy is directly related to science or mathematics then it is.